# R clients to OLAP MDX servers

Tags: r, mdx, olap, mondrian, xmla

Has anyone tried to access an OLAP server offering a XMLA API (such as Mondrian) from R?

I'd love to run MDX queries from R against Mondrian and retrieve result sets.

Comment: Are you considering Mondrian only ?

Comment: In principle, yes. Although other open source alternatives could also be considered.

Comment: Also interested in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on something here but I'm new to building R plug-in/extension.

I've begun by looking at RODBC and also gSOAP for this. Any other hints/tips?

Comment: I've finished an initial cut of "X4R" (XMLA for R), an XMLA/MDX client for R. It's been posted to github: https://github.com/overcoil/X4R

Comment: What is the 'structure' in R that matches the result of the MDX query ?

Comment: @ic3 `array` but it scale badly with dimensions and dimensions cardinality